# Angular 5 how to get Selected option text value from dropdown in component test

Tags: angular, testing, components

In an Angular component test, how can the sect value of a Select/dropdown be retrieved in a test?

I can get the value using `expect(selectElement.nativeElement.value).toBe('1');` but cant figure out how to get the Text value to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `.innerText` from the selected option:

```
var select = selectElement.nativeElement;
var text = select.options[select.selectedIndex].innerText
```